# Why does this sentence use と here?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

Consider the following sentence.

> 漢｛かん｝字｛じ｝試｛し｝験{けん}は理｛り｝解｛かい｝力｛りょく｝より記｛き｝憶｛おく｝力｛りょく｝を試｛ため｝すものだと批｛ひ｝判｛はん｝されています。

If I split it into two sentences, they might be as follows (correct if it is wrong):

> 漢｛かん｝字｛じ｝試｛し｝験{けん}は理｛り｝解｛かい｝力｛りょく｝より記｛き｝憶｛おく｝力｛りょく｝を試｛ため｝すものです。
>
> 漢｛かん｝字｛じ｝試｛し｝験{けん}は批｛ひ｝判｛はん｝されています。

In my understanding, と is used

- quoting:「勉強なさい」と言っていました。
- AND: コーヒーとミルクが好きです。
- IF: 押すとお金が出ます。

So what is the purpose of と in the above sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quotative.

> 漢字試験は理解力より記憶力を試すものだ**と**批判されています。

≒

> 漢字試験は、『理解力より記憶力を試すものだ。』**と**批判されています。

The 『～～～』 part is what some people have been saying about the test.